# How to manage "missing compliance" automatically on App store Test Flight?

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

[image]

I get this question at first and I always choose "Standart Encryption" .

Then It asks if the app will be available in France and I say no. So my question is how to manage this automatically so I don't have to wait processing of the app.

Comment: Unless you have implemented your own encryption code (or embedded a library such as OpenSSL) you probably want to answer "none of the above". However, follow the link in the screenshot to get the information on the keys to include in your info.plist to bypass this screen

Comment: what about france question ? @Paulw11

Answer (score 5):

If the answer to this question is, as I suspect, actually "None" then you don't need to provide any documentation for France.  Setting `ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption` to `NO` in your info.plist is all that is required.

If the answer is that you are using standard encryption algorithms instead of or in addition to Apple's libraries then you need to set `ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption` to `YES`. You will also need to [submit the required documentation for France to Apple](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev38f592ac9).

Once Apple have reviewed and approved your documents they will provide a value that you specify for the key `ITSEncryptionExportComplianceCode` in your Info.plist file.

Comment: It won't be available for france, so the answer should be no in that case. How can I achieve this?

Comment: First, are you sure you have an implementation of standard encryption algorithms in your app and aren't just using HTTPS and Apple's Crypto framework?  This is pretty unusual.  But, if you have, you still need to submit the appropriate documentation for the Us and receive the compliance code from Apple.

Comment: these apps have been available for years in stores, so I'm sure, but every time I send it to test flight I have to manage missing compliance. I selected "standard encrytion" and "no" for france question.

Comment: Then you will need to follow the link in my answer to get the compliance code from Apple.  Without a compliance code your only other option is to set `ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption` to `NO` which is the equivalent of selecting "None of the algorithms mentioned above".  You could also investigate whether you can remove your crypto implementation and just use Apple's framework.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add an entry to the info.plist as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/itsappusesnonexemptencryption):

```
ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption and set to NO
```